# How to Print celery worker details on windows and mac

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, worker

I actually had issues printing mine on command prompt because I was using the wrong command but I found a link to a project which I forked [Project](https://github.com/codertjay/TofaProject#run-celery-for-task)

- (If on Mac ) `celery -A Project worker --loglevel=info`
- (If on Windows) `celery -A Project worker -l info --pool=solo`

Comment: Can you specify your question? It sounds like you found the answer already. What exactly does not work as expected? What do you mean by "print celery worker details"? Do you want to have the celery worker print to console / terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```sh
celery -A Project worker --loglevel=info
```

in project folder where your **celery** object is created.
You can use the file name to get your tasks discovered.
For Example: if your file name is `tasks.py` and **celery** object is created in that file.
Command will be:

```sh
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

Comment: But it only worked but doesnt print on windows

Comment: This works for windows `celery -A Project worker -l info --pool=solo`